# SubSonic How to provide a column name in a generic method

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Using SubSonic3, I have this generic method (thanks to linq guy, James Curran):

```
    public List<T> GetFromList<T>( List<Guid> _IDs,
        Func<T, Guid> GetID,
        Func<IQueryable<T>> GetAll )
            where T : class, IActiveRecord
    {
        List<T> rc = null;
        var Results =
            from item in GetAll( )
            where ( _IDs as IEnumerable<Guid> ).Contains( GetID( item ) )
            select item;

        rc = Results.ToList<T>( );
        return rc;
    }
```

It is called with something like

```
List<Job> jresults = GetFromList( IDList,
    item => item.JobID,
    ( ) => Job.All( ) );
```

Where IDList is a List of guids that are keys to the table.

When not generic, the linq looks like this and works perfectly.  I was quite impressed that SubSonic's linq provider could take this code and turn it into SELECT * FROM Job WHERE JobID IN (a, b, c):

```
            var Results =
            from item in Job.All( )
            where ( _IDs as IEnumerable<Guid> ).Contains( item.JobID )
            select item;
```

I want to be able to call this method on tables other than Job, with keys other than JobID.  The GetAll Func works because it returns the same IQueryable that Job.All( ) does, but GetID throws a run-time exception, "LINQ expression node of type Invoke is not supported".  GetID returns a value, but what I really need from it is something that Contains( item.JobID) would recognize as a column name and that the "where" syntax would accept. (I don't show it here, but I have the same problem with orderby.)

Is that possible, with what you know of SubSonic3?

Comment: I've read through this a couple times, and I have to say I'm not sure what end result you're trying to achieve.  You show two code snippets that appear to achieve the same result - one using only LINQ and the ActiveRecord class and the other using your generic method.  Maybe you could add a snippet of what code you're trying to end up with that isn't working?  I'm thinking you are trying to use your generic method in a larger LINQ query, but again I'm really unsure.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. What I am trying to accomplish is to get the parameter of the Contains to be "item.JobID" when T is Job, but "item.WhateverID" when T is Whatever.  I have quite a few tables with search logic that is unique to each one; the search logic builds the List of Guids.  Once I have that, every table then has this very same logic to select the objects using WHERE "key" IN (Guid1, Guid2, ...).  Very same, I say, except for the table and key column.  GetAll resolves the problem for the table, but GetID doesn't resolve the problem of the column.  Is this any clearer?

Comment: I may have tunnel vision:  my REAL desired end result is the SQL Query SELECT * FROM Job WHERE JobID IN (a, b, c), where my generic method can work for (1) any table (besides Job), (2) any key (besides JobID), and (3) any list of key values.  I have (1) and (3), but not (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to pass in the expression that Where needed:

```
 public List<T> GetFromList( List<Guid> _IDs,
    Func<IQueryable<T>> GetAll,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> _where )
        where T : class, U, IActiveRecord
{
    List<T> rc = new List<T>( );
    if ( 0 < _IDs.Count )
    {
        if ( MAX_ITEMS > _IDs.Count )
        {
            var Results = GetAll( ).Where( _where );
            rc = Results.ToList( );
        }
        else
        {
            var Results =
                from id in _IDs
                join item in GetAll( ) on id equals item.KeyValue( )
                select item;
            rc = Results.ToList( );
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

called by

```
  rc = GetFromList(
      IDList,
      ( ) => Job.All( ),
      ( item => ( IDList as IEnumerable<Guid> ).Contains( item.JobID ) ) );
```